# Using bcrypt to make sure password hasn't been repeated

Tags: node.js, promise, bcrypt

I'm using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to hash passwords in the database. I'm trying to add a feature to make sure when a user cannot reuse passwords. What I would like to do is loop through a list of previous passwords to check for reuse. Right now I can do something simple like this:

```
var reused = false;
for (let i = 0; i < oldPWs.length; i++) {
   reused = bcrypt.compareSync(newPassword, oldPWs[i].PASSWORD);
   if (reused){
      console.log("Password is a repeat");
      break;
   }
}
```

However, according to the documentation doing this with the Sync function isn't recommended since it this can block other server requests. Is there a recommended method for checking if a password is valid for a list of hashes? I don't think it could be done with the callback function of the `bcrypt.compare()` function but maybe with promises... Any recommendations would be appreciated.

---

@Zhephard gave me a push in the right direction so I marked his answer as correct. The actual code I used is below:

```
var promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < oldPWs.length; i++) {
    promises.push(bcrypt.compare(newPassword, oldPWs[i].PASSWORD))
}

Promise.all(promises).then((results)=>{
    console.log("All done:", results)
    if (results.includes(true)) {
        // alert users password has been repeated
        console.log("Password is repeat")
    } else {
        // allow password change
        console.log("Password is new")
    }
})
```

Comment: Where is the list of old passwds coming from? If it is in a database can you do the compare there ?

Comment: So use the asynchronous `bcrypt.compare()` instead? https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-check-a-password

Comment: Aside from an issue of *"blocking"*, there is also the issue that calculating a bcrypt hash *should* take about ~250 ms of CPU time. That means in order to check that the user isn't attempting to re-use one of their last 9 passwords, it will take 2,250 ms of pure CPU time. That's not a great thing. The real issue is the password policy that is preventing old password reuse. Get rid of that policy to make the system more secure.

Comment: @IanBoyd I'm confused... Wouldn't a policy to prevent password reuse be more secure than to allow users to keep reusing passwords.

Comment: It forces users to come up with weaker passwords so they can remember them, since they can't use the one they would like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what i read on the API you seem to be doing the right thing, if using promises is one of your options you could do something like

```js
oldPWs.map((p) => bcrypt.compare(p.PASSWORD, hash)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res) console.log('Password repeated');
  }));
```

This way is quite short, and you don't have to mind using indexes across the old retrieved passwords as well

Comment: I was able to use your answer to help solve my problem. I switched to promises but had to run all promises before I could move allow the user to change their password.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

To do this, you would probably make an asynchronous function like so

```
//Non blocking bcrypt
async function reuse_check(plaintext, oldPw) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (res, rej){
        bcrypt.compare(plaintext, oldPw, function(err, BCRYPT_RES){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                if (BCRYPT_RES) {
                    res(true)
                }
                else {
                    res(false)
                }
            }
        })
    })
    let isReused = await promise
    return isReused


}

//Loops, await is valid in async only
async function looper(plaintext, oldPwsArray) {
    var reused = false
    for (let i = 0; i < oldPwsArray.length; i++) {
        var temp = await reuse_check(plaintext, oldPwsArray[i])
        if (temp) {
            reused = true
            break
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    if (reused) {
        console.log("Reused")
    }
}

//Driver
looper(plaintext, oldPwsArray)
```

This should fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.
Using bcrypt.compare() with no callback returns promise.
And you can wait for bcrypt.comapre() and break() immediately if you find the same password.

```
(async () => {
    for(let i=0 ; oldPWs.length; i++){
        try {
            let isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(newPassword, oldPWs[i].PASSWORD);
            if(isEqual){
                console.log("Password is a repeat");
                break;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('something wrong');
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
})();
```